# Passing data between ViewControllers (again)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm very sorry guys, I know this question has been asked before. But after 4 Hours of searching, I couldn't find a nice explanation.

So what I want to do: I have a tableView, where the User can select something (by using AccessoryCheckmark). When the "back" Button in UINavigationBar is touched (viewWillDisappear) I want to send the selected Row (i have a array called "selectedRowArray" which correctly gives me the selected Value) back to it's previous NavigationController.
I read about AppDelegates, @propertys, delegates and (properly the "nastiest" way:) NSUserDefaults.

Please, could someone tell me, which is the best (smartest) way, to pass my data from tableView2 BACK to tableView1?

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you don't understand. As you say, there's already plenty of information out there, including on SO itself, about this. What _exactly_ are you having trouble with? What have you done, and where are you stuck? What information are you looking for that isn't already contained in those other sources?

Answer (score 1):

Make the previous view controller a delegate of the selection view controller.

From the selection view controller call a delegate method on the previous view controller to tell it what was selected.

Basically, they key is to use a delegate.  Make the delegate that gets set a weak property of your selection controller (which means you are targeting iOS 5 or higher, which you should be).

A protocol is optional.

Answer (score 0):

For sending data to a previous view in your view controller stack (navigation stack) then you can use the following snippet:

```
int previous = self.navigationController.viewControllers.count - 2;
UIViewController *controller = [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:previous];
controller.arrayProperty = @[];  //array element to pass into whatever specified property
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Of course be sure to change UIViewController to the previous views class name and make sure the property is created in that previous view controller header file like so:

```
@property(strong)NSArray *arrayProperty;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation and I am new to ios dev, so I would want you to take my answer just as a lead. Even I had to search numerous hours before I came to a simple thing.

I was having tough time with @protocol and delegates.

I found a tutorial (which i currently can not locate), what it basically does is define a property in your nextViewController and sets its value from prevViewController

```
//nextViewController.h

@interface nextViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *searchString;
@end

// prevController.h

import "NextViewController.h"
@property (weak, nonatomic) PrevViewController *prevViewController;

// prevController.m
-someMethodFromWhereYouWantToSetTheProperty {
   prevViewController.searchString = self.yourvalue;
}
```

EDIT:

I have already pointed out that I am a newbie to ios dev. So, I am not very certain if this is the right way or if it has any drawbacks.

Comment: This tightly couples `NextViewController` to `PrevViewController`. To avoid this, it's better to use a protocol. EDIT: in response to your edit - the drawback is now you can never use `NextViewController` without `PrevViewController`.

Answer (score -1):

Braydens way is indeed nice, but I would prefer making a singleton, it's nice and easy to handle. Make the singleton store your properties. You can also always check if property is nil.

Comment: Unless the data needs to be generally & centrally available as part of the entire model layer of your application this is an inappropriate use of the Singleton pattern IMO. Should be used for abstracting more or less singular resources e.g. db access, network access, etc. Passing simple values to a parent view controller is not a good use for this.

Comment: I agree with @Carl Veazey. Singletons are appropriate when you need to share data globablly. A delegate is the right way to handle this case, in my opinion.